# SQLite SELECT * FROM Command Not Working for Value of 10

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

I have an SQLite problem.

I have a `text not null` column `LAST_COLUMN` where I have numbers stored as text. If that number is 10, it does not retrieve the column! Forget android code, I have used an SQLite Browser to give commands of SELECT * FROM and it doesn't get the column where the values is 10. If it is 9, 11, 20 or 240 it does get them. This problem is giving me problems in my android code as well.

I use the SQLite command

```sql
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE LAST_COLUMN = '10'
```

. Any idea as to what the problem might be?

Thanks.

EDIT: Okay so the problem is not with the number 10, but with my writing of the SQLite Database. Whatever I do even though the numbers in the last column appear to be what they are supposed to be, SQLite Commands do not recognize that. WTH?:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cases like this it usually means that your "misbehaving" value (in your case `10`) has leading/trailing spaces in  it.

You can find all these "bad" records with a query

```
SELECT *
  FROM Table1
 WHERE LENGTH(last_column) <> LENGTH(TRIM(last_column))
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/d9883/1)** demo

And you can obviously fix them with a simple update

```
UPDATE Table1
   SET last_column = TRIM(last_column)
 WHERE LENGTH(last_column) <> LENGTH(TRIM(last_column))
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/3c198/2)** demo

---

If you need to deal with special characters like `\r`, `\n`, `\t` then you can use `REPLACE()` and/or `TRIM(X,Y)`

```
SELECT *
  FROM Table1
 WHERE LENGTH(last_column) <> 
       LENGTH(TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(last_column, x'0900',''), x'0D00', ''), x'0A00', '')))
```

to fix values removing these special characters

```
UPDATE table1
   SET last_column = TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(last_column, x'0900',''), x'0D00', ''), x'0A00', ''))
 WHERE LENGTH(last_column) <> 
       LENGTH(TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(last_column, x'0900',''), x'0D00', ''), x'0A00', '')))
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/69fb2/3)** demo

Comment: Do you mean like \r, \n?

Comment: I meant spaces as usual space `' '`, but if you loaded your data from a file then yes you can also probably have characters like `\r`, `\n`, `\t`.

Comment: You were right. I fixed the issue a while back by using `replaceAll()`. Does your code get trim those as well?

Comment: @AhmedZafar See updated answer for a solution dealing with special characters. And if you feel like the answer was helpful please, consider to **[accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** the answer.